# Moving time machine backup sparsebundle from Time Capsule to USB exFAT disk

Tags: backup, time-machine, external-disk, time-capsule

I have a Time Machine backup on an Airport Time Capsule (name: `computername.sparsebundle`). Now I want to access that backup on a USB disk formatted as exFAT.

Several online resources describe the migration **to** a Time Capsule. My question relates to the opposite migration, away from the Time Capsule.

Is this possible? If so, how can I migrate this backup from the Airport Time Capsule (sparsebundle) to a USB disk formatted as exFAT?

Comment: Not sure this will work as Time Machine **requires** HFS+.

Comment: You can run Time Machine on "unsupported" file systems. The steps involved, include the creation of a sparsebundle with Disk Utility and then some command-line magic. See for instance https://mybyways.com/blog/using-an-exfat-drive-for-time-machine-backups

Comment: Time Machine doesn't require HFS+ – but it does require one of HFS+ or APFS

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say you migrating time machine backup to exFAT is a relatively long thing to do. However, if you want to *just* access the files from a exFAT formatted drive you can simply copy those files to that drive. Though this is not a great solution.

If it's possible try other options. Do not limit yourself to use exFAT.

Comment: I decided to create a `sparseimage` disk image on the external exFAT disk. I'm now copying the latest backup from the Time Capsule to that `sparse image` disk image. Sadly the connection (mounted `sparsebundle`) with the Time Capsule drops frequently.